# Porque este código não está a calcular a média corretamente?

Tags: c#, matemática

Eu provavelmente hoje devo estar muito mau em matemática para não conseguir fazer um código simples que calcule a média de dois valores... Eu simplesmente não entendo o que fiz errado...
BTW, espero que a média seja calculada assim...(soma de vários valores / quantidade de valores; neste caso `valor1 + valor2 /2`)

```
double valor1 = 0; // Valor a calcular
double valor2 = 0; // Segundo valor a calcular
double resultado = 0; // Variável para mostrar o resultado

Console.Write("Escreva o primeiro valor da para calcular a média: "); // Perguntar o primeiro valor
valor1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Leitura + conversão da string para double
//
Console.Write("Escreva o segundo valor: "); // Perguntar o segundo valor
valor2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Leitura + conversão da string para double

resultado = valor1 + valor2 / 2; // Cálculo da média -> valor1 + valor2 / 2

Console.WriteLine("O resultado é: " + resultado); // Mostrar o resultado
Console.Read(); // Pausar a aplicação e permitir o utilizador ler o resultado
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado que está dando? Você chegou a testar colocando o `valor1` e o `valor2` entre parenteses? Tipo, `(valor1 + valor2)/2`?

Comment: @Willian Se por exemplo, o primeiro valor for 10 e o segundo for 5 o resultado é 12,5. Eu acho que deveria ser 7,5 ou não sei matemática???

Comment: Da uma olhada no comentário acima, você está esquecendo os parênteses que separam a soma da divisão. Se você não colocar a soma no parênteses, a conta irá fazer primeiro a divisão e depois a soma

Comment: @Willian Não sabia que isso era possível em C#, pensava que apenas permitia cálculos "simples"... Vou tentar! Se funcionar, obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme apresentado nos comentários, o erro está no `resultado = valor1 + valor2 /2`.

Pela matemática, se você quiser que a soma seja feita antes da divisão, você tem de colocar a soma entre parênteses e depois dividir. No caso ficaria:

`resultado = (valor1 + valor2) / 2`

Comment: Muito obrigado por explicar que era possível executar cálculos deste tipo em C#, parece que tenho ainda tenho muito a aprender... :)

Comment: Por nada, boa sorte :D

Answer (score 4):

O problema se encontra na linha:

`resultado = valor1 + valor2 / 2;`

Acontece que a operação de divisão e multiplicação sempre tem prioridade sobre a adição e subtração, caso você queira especificar que uma adição é mais importante no seu contexto você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
resultado = (valor1 + valor2) / 2;
```

Dessa forma a adição será executada primeiro e o resultado será divido pelo número 2.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas alguém respondeu primeiro... Mas obrigado pela ajuda na mesma :D

Comment: De nada, boa sorte na sua jornada.